# How to merge column in mysql depending on match

Tags: mysql

I have one table which looks like this in mysql

```
column1  column2    name    column3 data
1          1        foo     1       1.5
1          1        foo     2       2.5
1          1        foo     3       3.5
1          1        foo     4       4.5
1          1        foo2    1       1.1
1          1        foo2    2       3.5
1          1        foo3    3       5.6
1          1        foo3    4       6.7
```

I want to do query like something like this, I really don't know how to write as I am new to mysql

```
select name from mytable where name = 'foo' or name = 'foo2'or name = 'foo3'
```

I expect output to be like this

```
column1 column2 column3    foo    foo2  foo3
1       1         1        1.5     1.1  NaN
1       1         2        2.5     3.5  NaN
1       1         3        3.5     NaN  5.6
1       1         4        4.5     NaN  6.7
```

Is it possible in mysql ?

Comment: This is called a pivot table. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT column1,column2,column3
MAX(CASE WHEN name='foo' THEN data ELSE 0 END)as foo,
MAX(CASE WHEN name='foo2' THEN data ELSE 0 END)as foo2,
MAX(CASE WHEN name='foo3' THEN data ELSE 0 END)as foo3
FROM tableName
GROUP BY column3
```

Comment: Thank you so much its working, I wanted to vote but no reputation, so am just accepting please don't mind, can you explain case part ?

Comment: Case its like an if,if name=some value then choose data column  corresponding to that value.This is called a pivot query.

Comment: @Mihai its ok to update the answer to sure it is right :) and user will have the right answer ,nothing needed

Answer (score 1):

Try this [**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6841d/2)

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3,
MAX(CASE WHEN NAME='foo' THEN DATA ELSE 0 END)AS foo,
MAX(CASE WHEN NAME='foo2' THEN DATA ELSE 0 END)AS foo2,
MAX(CASE WHEN NAME='foo3' THEN DATA ELSE 0 END)AS foo3
FROM Table2
GROUP BY col3
```