# how would i merge a column where matches a different column?

Tags: mysql, merge

It's very similar to the below post

[How to merge column in mysql depending on match](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61366/how-to-merge-column-in-mysql-depending-on-match)

table user

[image]

I would like to Merge customer_id from table user to table cust where customers_firstname AND customers_name match

table cust

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply update with join if you want to update the cust table

```
update cust c 
join user u on u.customers_firstname = c.customers_firstname
and u.customers_lastname = c.customers_lastname
set c.customers_id = u.customers_id
```

Comment: Let me know if i got it straight, `update cust c` sets cust = c, `join user u` sets user = u, `on` is like where to join, `set` sets the update. correct?

Comment: set should be after the join clause as shown in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I get this error `#1054 - Unknown column 'u.customer_firstname' in 'on clause'`

Comment: I think I missed `s` in `customers_firstname` and same for lastname

Comment: Thanks, please edit this too `set c.customers_id = u.customers_id`

Comment: would  this be vaild code? i added a condition if c.customers_id is null,  `update cust c 
join user u on u.customers_firstname = c.customers_firstname
and u.customers_lastname = c.customers_lastname
and c.customers_id = null
set c.customers_id = u.customers_id`

Comment: It should be `and c.customers_id is null` `=null` is not valid